# If I were you, I would + verb (same expression in the present tense)

Tags: sentence-construction, subjunctives

I would like to know the exact form of the following structure in the **present tense**:

```
If I were you, I would + verb
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is based on a false premise.

> If I were you, I would ask for a refund

is not in the past tense despite the use of verbal forms primarily used for the past tense. It is a conditional sentence that relates to the present. If you want to refer to past in this kind of sentence

> If I had been you, I would have asked for a refund.

With this particular sentence, casting it into the furure does not make sense, but a different example will show how to deal with conditionals relating to the future.

> If I ever get in that situation, I will ask for a refund.

It is a bit strange. You can form conditionals in the following way

Past: If verb in past perfect, then would + verb in present perfect.

Present: If verb in past, then would + verb in present.

Future: If verb in present, then will (shall) + verb in present.